# How to install Mac OS theme on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: macbook

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. As I was inspired by mac OS theme, I want to install that theme in my PC. Can you suggest me the way to install it in my PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Cairo dock. It has many themes including MAC like theme.

Answer (score 1):

See this [post on NoobsLab](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/11/install-mac-os-x-theme-on-ubuntu-1210.html) and simply follow the directions.

It looks nice. There's a Firefox theme, Wallpapers, Cairo Dock, an icon set - the full package.

You can find other Mac themes besides this on Google, too.